# What in my functions and procedures is causing Stack overflow?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am trying to add my three functions together inside a procedure. The functions are `CalcOilLubeCharges`, `CalcMiscCharges`, and `CalcFlushCharges`. I am getting a stack over flow warning after trying to call the functions adding them together and setting them equal to a variable.

```
public Class frmTGAutomotie
    '   Function ValidateInputs() As Boolean
    '     Return
    'End Function
    ' Calculate all oil and lubrication charges
    Function CalcOilLubeCharges() As Decimal
        Const Oil = 36.0
        Const Lube = 28.0
        If chkOil.Checked Then
            CalcOilLubeCharges = CInt(CalcOilLubeCharges() + Oil)
        End If
        If chkLube.Checked Then
            CalcOilLubeCharges = CInt(CalcOilLubeCharges() + Lube)
        End If
        Return CalcOilLubeCharges
    End Function
    ' Calculate radiator and transmission flush charges
    Function CalcFlushCharges() As Decimal
        Const Radiator = 50.0
        Const Transmission = 120.0
        If chkRadiator.Checked Then
            CalcFlushCharges = CInt(CalcFlushCharges() + Radiator)
        End If
        If chkTransmission.Checked Then
            CalcFlushCharges = CInt(CalcFlushCharges() + Transmission)
        End If


        Return CalcFlushCharges
    End Function
    ' Calc Misc charges
    Function CalcMiscCharges() As Decimal
        Const Inspection = 36.0
        Const Muffler = 200.0
        Const Rotation = 20.0
        If chkInspection.Checked Then
            CalcMiscCharges = CInt(CalcMiscCharges + Inspection)
        End If
        If chkMuffler.Checked Then
            CalcMiscCharges = CInt(CalcMiscCharges + Muffler)
        End If
        If chkTireRotation.Checked Then
            CalcMiscCharges = CInt(CalcMiscCharges + Rotation)
        End If
        Return CalcMiscCharges
    End Function

    'Calculate and display the total of all charges,
    ' including labor, parts, and services.
    Sub CalculateTotalCharges()

        Dim TotalCharges As Decimal
        TotalCharges = CalcMiscCharges() + CalcOilLubeCharges() + CalcFlushCharges()
        lbTotalFeesOutput.Text = TotalCharges.ToString
    End Sub
    'Clear
    Sub ClearOilLube()
        chkOil.Checked = False
        chkLube.Checked = False

    End Sub
    'Clear
    Sub ClearFlushes()
        chkTransmission.Checked = False
        chkRadiator.Checked = False
    End Sub
    'Clear
    Sub ClearMisc()
        chkInspection.Checked = False
        chkMuffler.Checked = False
        chkTireRotation.Checked = False
    End Sub
    'Clear
    Sub ClearOthers()
        txtPartsDollars.Clear()
        txtLaborMinutes.Clear()
    End Sub


    Private Sub GroupBox2_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grpMisc.Enter

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbOilPrice.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbDollarSign4.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label15_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbDollarSign7.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        ClearOilLube()
        ClearFlushes()
        ClearMisc()
        ClearOthers()

    End Sub

    Private Sub lbTotalFeesOutput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbTotalFeesOutput.Click


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

        CalculateTotalCharges()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPartsDollars_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPartsDollars.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger tell you? There's not a lot of code here, so stepping though it should only take a few minutes.

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary code in your question (i.e. Empty subs & code that has nothing to do with the calculation). Try declaring a variable to be returned from your functions instead of using the function name (eg. `CalcOilLubeCharges`) & you should see the problem.

Comment: `CalcOilLubeCharges = CInt(CalcOilLubeCharges() + Oil)` (setting and calling itself to exhaustion)

Comment: Seems you're using the function's identifier as though it were some local variable. While that might have worked in VB6/VBA (though I wouldn't recommend doing that), VB.NET uses a `Return` statement, so there's no more "assign the function's return value to the function's identifier" - assuming a recursive function is accidental, declare and use a local variable instead of assigning to the function's identifier.

Comment: Looks like your class needs to hold some instance-level state.

Comment: You can still use the function name as an identifier in .NET (and there are occasions where it makes for the most concise code), but in order to do so, you need to delete the parens, which make it a function call instead of a reference to the implicit result variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the first Function to see where it goes wrong.

```
Function CalcOilLubeCharges() As Decimal
      Const Oil = 36.0
      Const Lube = 28.0
      If chkOil.Checked Then
          CalcOilLubeCharges = CInt(CalcOilLubeCharges() + Oil)
      End If
```

The first line declares a Function with the name CalcOilLubeCharges and the return type Decimal

The next 2 line declare constants. The compiler has no idea that you wish to deal with Decimal (preferred when dealing with money) so it assumes Double. You can tell this by holding your cursor over `Oil` and `Lube`. To correct this place a `D` after the number.

Let's assume that `chkOil` is checked. **Now comes the trouble.**

```
CalcOilLubeCharges = CInt(CalcOilLubeCharges() + Lube)
```

The right side of the assignment calls `CalcOilLubeCharges`, the method we are in. You may have incorrectly assumed that this is a variable but it is the name of a `Function`. This happens over and over until we get a stack overflow.

To correct this use a locally declared variable to hold the values.

I have also showed you a short cut way to do the addition with `+=`.

```
Function CalcOilLubeCharges() As Decimal
    Const Oil = 36D
    Const Lube = 28D
    Dim LubeOilCharge As Decimal
    If chkOil.Checked Then
        LubeOilCharge += Oil
    End If
    If chkLube.Checked Then
        LubeOilCharge += Lube
    End If
    Return LubeOilCharge
End Function

Function CalcFlushCharges() As Decimal
    Const Radiator = 50D
    Const Transmission = 120D
    Dim Flush As Decimal
    If chkRadiator.Checked Then
        Flush += Radiator
    End If
    If chkTransmission.Checked Then
        Flush += Transmission
    End If
    Return Flush
End Function

Function CalcMiscCharges() As Decimal
    Const Inspection = 36D
    Const Muffler = 200D
    Const Rotation = 20D
    Dim Misc As Decimal
    If chkInspection.Checked Then
        Misc += Inspection
    End If
    If chkMuffler.Checked Then
        Misc += Muffler
    End If
    If chkTireRotation.Checked Then
        Misc += Rotation
    End If
    Return Misc
End Function

Sub CalculateTotalCharges()
    Dim TotalCharges As Decimal
    TotalCharges = CalcMiscCharges() + CalcOilLubeCharges() + CalcFlushCharges()
    lbTotalFeesOutput.Text = TotalCharges.ToString("N2")
End Sub
```

Comment: The function name can also be used as an implicit result variable, but in order to do it, it would need to be done without the trailing parens (which turn it into a function call instead).

Comment: @Craig I wondered about that because the OP had one without parens. I have never done it that way. Thanks for the heads up.